# codeigniter: get single field from from an array in same method

Tags: codeigniter

How do I get only email from this array in same method to pass as variable for the model?

```
$user_data['userinfo'] = $this->logindatamodel->login_data();
$tsp = $this->AttendanceModel->get_batch_byUser();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [userinfo] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [Name] => Md. Aminur Rahman
            [Email] => aminur.biswas@yahoo.com
            [Password] => 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
            [Role] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do,

```
 echo $user_data['userinfo']->Email
```

you will get the email printed 
and this is the solution for only single dimensional array.If it is multidimensional

you will put it on a loop and

```
echo $user_data['userinfo'][0]->Email;
```

or

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($user_data['userinfo'];$i++)
{
   echo $user_data['userinfo'][$i]->Email;
}
```